# How to make changes in sub-report added in detailed section?

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

How to make changes in sub-report in detail section when it is not visible ?

I want to make changes in sub-report which is added in detail section
at design time.

```
Problem : Details section is not visible.
```

Explanation : I have Report A and two sub-reports B and C. Firstly, when i have designed the report i was able to make changes. But when i copied the report to some different location to make changes in it, the detail section with sub-reports is not visible.

Could any one please tell what problem is this.

I am stuck of this. Please help.

Comment: Location mean? another report or subreport? your question is confusing

Comment: @siva Actually, i have copied the same file some where else and open that file in crystal report. Then, the detail section is not expandable, so that i can make changes in sub-report already added in detail section.

Comment: It means your detail section is there but not expandable. is that correct? It looks to be a wierd problem normally you should be able to expand the detail section.

Comment: One more thing i have noticed is that when i am closing the preview, and then save the file and close it and reopen it, then also detail section is not expandable and sub-reports are also closed.

Comment: If you completely close the report and reopen then subreport will be closed by default it is a normal behaviour amy be your installation of the crystal reprots may has some issue.

Comment: But at least the detail section should be expandable..

Comment: Thats great what was the solution

Comment: just select show hidden sections in options. It will show you the detail section which is hidden...